# Calling a VBA form from a button causes UserForm_Initialize to run twice, breaking my code?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello wonderful VBA community,
I'm still really new to vba and am trying to learn a lot. Thank you in advance for looking through my code and my description of the issue I'm facing.

I have a button on a page that calls a new Userform.

**CODE SNIPPET 1:**

```
Sub btnShowDetails_Click()
    Call frmShowDeets.ShowDeets
End Sub
```

... which calls the next bit of code in the 'frmShowDeets' UserForm:

**CODE SNIPPET 2:**

```
Public Sub ShowDeets()

Dim frm As frmShowDeets
Set frm = New frmShowDeets 'this line triggers the Userform_Initialize() event below
  frm.Show

End Sub
```

... triggering:

**CODE SNIPPET 3:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim comboBoxItem As Range

For Each comboBoxItem In ContactList.Range("tblContactList[CompanyName]")
                                            '^refers to unique values in a named range
  With Me.boxCompanySelection
    .AddItem comboBoxItem.Value
  End With
Next comboBoxItem

End Sub
```

So at this point, the form I want to display has values loaded in its one combobox for user selection. The user selects a company and the Combobox_Change event triggers other routines that pull information for that company.

**CODE SNIPPET 4:**

```
Public Sub boxCompanySelection_Change()
  Call frmShowDeets.PullData
End Sub

Sub PullData()
Dim numCompanies As Long
  numCompanies = ContactList.Range("B6").Value 'this holds a count of the rows in the named range
Dim FoundCell As Range
  Set FoundCell = ContactList.Range("tblContactList[Company Name]").Find(What:=boxCompanySelection.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Dim CompanyRow As Long
  CompanyRow = FoundCell.Row

With ContactList
  'pull a bunch of the company's details
End With
End Sub
```

Here is where it gets weird... Once the form is shown and the user selects one of the combo box items, triggering the Combobox_Change event the code breaks because the 'What:=boxCompanySelection.Text' part of the Range().Find method reads as "" empty (even though Code Snippet 3 is meant to load in company names and Code Snippet 4 is only triggered when the user selects one of those company names from the combobox) and I shouldn't need to build something to handle 'not found' exceptions since the only possible values should be the ones pulled in from my named range.

From stepping through the code, I have determined that for some reason, Code Snippets 2 and 3 run **TWICE** before Snippet 4 is run. Does anyone know what about my code is causing this to happen? I'm thinking there's a disconnect between the form that is shown and loaded with combobox values and whatever Code Snippet 4 is reading data from.

What is weirder is that if I run the code starting from Code Snippet 2 (ignoring the button call in Code Snippet 1), the form works as intended and from what I can tell 2 and 3 are only run once.

The problem is probably something simple I'm overlooking but I just cannot figure out what it is. Thanks again!

Comment: Try to replace the Call `frmShowDeets.PullData to` `Me.PullData`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for linking that article. That explains a lot about what is happening behind the code that I did not previously know. Your TLDR is fantastic information; THANK YOU SO MUCH! :)

Comment: @NelmanJayLouieVasquez For the purposes of making my process work, that fix did it! Thank you so much! Based on MathiewGuindon's answer, it sounds like changing from 'frmShowDeets' to 'Me' directs the sub to invoke PullData() on the second form instance?

Comment: Note that `ShowDeets` is also superfluous. The answer below explains why the `Initialize` handler runs twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that a form is an object - exactly as any other class module, except a form happens to have a designer and a *base class*, so `UserForm1` inherits the members of the `UserForm` class.

A form also has a *default instance*, and a lot of tutorials just happily skip over that very important but rather technical bit, which takes us exactly here on Stack Overflow, with a bug involving global state accidentally stored on the default instance.

```
Call frmShowDeets.ShowDeets
```

Assuming `frmShowDeets` is the name of the form class, and assuming this is the first reference to that form that gets to run, then the `UserForm_Initialize` handler *of the default instance* runs when the `.` dot operator executes and dereferences the object. *Then* the `ShowDeets` method runs.

```
Public Sub ShowDeets()

Dim frm As frmShowDeets
Set frm = New frmShowDeets 'this line triggers the Userform_Initialize() event below
  frm.Show

End Sub
```

That line triggers `UserForm_Initialize` *on the local instance* named `frm` - which is an entirely separate object, of the same class. The `Initialize` handler runs whenever an instance of a class is, well, initialized, i.e. created. The `Terminate` handler runs when that instance is destroyed.

So `ShowDeets` is acting as some kind of "factory method" that creates & shows a new instance of the `frmShowDeets` class/form - in other words whatever happened on the default instance is irrelevant beyond that point: the object you're working with exists in the `ShowDeets` scope, is named `frm`, and gets destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope.

Remove the `ShowDeets` method altogether. Replace this:

```
Call frmShowDeets.ShowDeets
```

With this:

```
With New frmShowDeets
    .Show
End With
```

Now the `Initialize` handler no longer runs on the default instance.

What you want, is to avoid using the default instance at all. Replace all `frmShowDeets` in the form's code-behind, with `Me` (see [Understanding 'Me' (no flowers, no bees)](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/09/05/understanding-me-no-flowers-no-bees/)), so that no state ever accidentally gets stored in the default instance.

```
Call frmShowDeets.PullData
```

Becomes simply:

```
Call Me.PullData
```

Or even:

```
PullData
```

Since `Call` is never required anywhere, and the `Me` qualifier is always implicit when you make a member call in a class module's code.